# Как правильно сформировать ajax в jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Сейчас есть ajax запрос, который написан на чистом js. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно перезаписать запрос ajax jquery?

```js
let servResponce = document.querySelector('#responce');

document.forms.ourForm.onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let userInput = document.forms.ourForm.ourForm_input.value;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', 'some.php');

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            servResponce.textContent = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send('ourForm_inp=' + userInput)

    $xhr.ajax ({
        url: '/some.php',
        context: 'document.body'
    }).done(function() {
        $(  ).addClass( "done" );
    })


}




$.ajax({
    url: '/some.php',         /* Куда отправить запрос */
    method: 'get',             /* Метод запроса (post или get) */
    dataType: 'html',          /* Тип данных в ответе (xml, json, script, html). */
    data: {text: 'Текст'},     /* Данные передаваемые в массиве */
    success: function(data){   /* функция которая будет выполнена после успешного запроса.  */
        console.log(12111); /* В переменной data содержится ответ от index.php. */
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="responce"></div>
<form  name="ourForm">
    <input type="text" name="ourForm_input">

    <button type="submit" name="ourForm_btn">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Заготовка у вас есть, но я бы отправлял методом POST. А вместо `data: {text: 'Текст'},` написал бы что-то вроде: `data: {'ourForm_inp': $('#userInput')}`, если, конечно, в вашей форме есть инпут с id='userInput'. Если надо отправить не одно, а несколько полей, то тогда стоило бы сериализовать все поля формы.

Comment: @Quazimorda попробовал записать так как вы сказали,  но вышла ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно её исправить?

Comment: В приведённом вами куске кода нет переменной stepUp, значит ошибка происходит в другом месте кода. Собственно в ошибке сказано, что stepUP (очевидно, функция) вызвана для объекта, в котором не реализован интерфейс HTMLInputElement. Стало быть. разбирайтесь в коде.

Answer (score 3):

В текущем случае, если поставить на инпут идентификатор, например `id="test"`, то можно так:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some.php',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { text: $('#test').val() },
    success: function(data){ 
        console.log(12111); 
    }
});
```

Если на форме много инпутов и данных, то можно на форму добавить идентификатор, например  `#my-form` и отправить сериализованную форму

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some.php',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: $('#my-form').serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        console.log(12111);
    }
});
```

Если форма супер большая и полей ооооочень много, то рекомендую отправлять данные через POST и желательно через `JSON.stringify`

---

> Сейчас есть ajax запрос, который написан на чистом js.

У вас суперстарый подход в отправке данных. Поэтому нужно изучить **[fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)**  и желательно async/await (**[тык](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)**, **[тык](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await)**)  и тогда jquery для отправи запросов не понадобится

Comment: Кстати, да, я про val() в своём комментарии совсем забыл.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь всё понял